# How to know the form from a submit

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I have several forms in a page and in each form a submit. But it is not working because this return me the two forms. Someone know to do it?

Thanks

```
$(".submit").click(function() {
    processBeforeSend($(".submit").closest("form"));
});


 function processBeforeSend(form) {

form.each($('input'), function() {

    if ($(this).attr('class') == 'integer'){
        validateInteger(field);
    }
    else{
        if (filedClass == 'radio'){
            validateRadio(field);
        }
        else{

        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Using `click` instead of `submit` means that keyboard submission will bypass your code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the `form` which contains the clicked `.submit` element, for that you can use `this` to refer to the clicked `.submit` element inside the click handler

```
$(".submit").click(function() {
    processBeforeSend($(this).closest("form"));
});
```

Comment: Note: Using `click` instead of `submit` means that keyboard submission will bypass the function.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the `submit` button's click event, I would just let the `submit` button do it's job -- trigger the form's `submit` event:

```
$("form").on( 'submit', processBeforeSend );


function processBeforeSend() {

    //'this' in here refers to the form whose submit event was triggered.
    $(this).find('input').each(function(i, field) {
        //'field' was not defined but in here it equals 'this' 
        //and refers to the current input element

        //An element can have more than one class so $(this).attr('class') is not the way to go.
        if( $(this).hasClass('integer') ){
            validateInteger(field);
        } else if( $(this).hasClass('radio') ) {
             validateRadio(field);
        } else {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `sumbit`? Is that binary maths :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `click` instead of `submit` means that keyboard submission will bypass your code! Always use the `submit` event instead for forms. If you use the `submit` event your `this` *is* the `form` :)

Also, your validation probably requires the form to "not" submit if validation fails. So pass the event object to your validation and call `e.preventDefault()` if any validation fails.

e.g.

```
$(".submit").submit(function(e) {
    processBeforeSend($(this), e);
});

function processBeforeSend(form, e) {
    // validation calls 
    if (somethingFails){
        e.preventDefault()
    }
});
```